# requirejs non-amd script requires global from amd module dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm trying to create a shim configuration in RequireJS, that boils down to this example:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths:{
        'non-amd-script' : 'path-to/non-amd-script', 
        'amd-module' : 'path-to/amd-module'
    },
    shim: {
        'non-amd-script' : { deps: ['amd-module'] }
    }
});
```

These scripts (the non-amd module one, at least) were 'designed' to just be included like:

```
<script src="amd-module'></script>
<script src="non-amd-script'></script>
```

But I want to load them asynchronously, with dependencies and whatnot, using [requireJS](https://requirejs.org/).

**Important note**:

1. (this is what drives my question) both `non-amd-script` and
   `amd-module` are scripts that are immutable (i.e. they are provided,
   and I cannot modify their source, as changes get lost on updates to
   these scripts).
2. I generate my shim configs with PHP (don't ask...) and I can't 'smell' these edge-cases.

### What I want

If required for a page, I initiate the loading of `non-amd-script` via a require-call:

```
require(['non-amd-script'], function(loadedModule) { //do stuff if the module returns stuff });
```

### The problem

While this works (`amd-module` loads first, then `non-amd-script`), it turns out that `non-amd-script` requires the return of `amd-module` in a global variable.

The `amd-module` in question is [Micromodal](https://github.com/Ghosh/micromodal) which, if loaded in-page, will register to the `window.MicroModal`, but since it is module-aware, it will not do that when loaded through requirejs.

The fact that it is module-aware will make any additional shim config ineffective (like `exports` or `init`), as these will be ignored for AMD modules (AFAIK).

### What I've tried

One 'solution' that I've tried, and which works, is this:

```
    shim: {
        'non-amd-script' : {
            deps: ['amd-module'],
            init: function(MicroModal) { window.MicroModal = MicroModal; return this; } 
        }
    }
```

But I don't really feel confortable using this, because as said, I generate my shim configs with PHP and need to do this for some/lots of other scripts (with possibly the same issues).

### My question

How can I make a `non-amd-script` play nice with the `amd-module` it depends on, if the latter doesn't register any of the globals used in `non-amd-script`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a proxy module which will require the `amd-module` and make it global. We can call it `amd-module-proxy`. Then you can use it in the shim as dependency for `non-amd-script`.

Here is a sample code:

```js
// amd-module-proxy.js
define(['amd-module'], function (MicroModal) {
  window.MicroModal = MicroModal;
});
```

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths:{
        'non-amd-script' : 'path-to/non-amd-script', 
        'amd-module' : 'path-to/amd-module',
        'amd-module-proxy': 'path-to/amd-module-proxy'
    },
    shim: {
        'non-amd-script' : { deps: ['amd-module-proxy'] }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Damian! This is an elegant solution, and one which I have also considered. But this is very script-specific; I'm looking for a way to make it work without having to set any specific globals. 
In this case, I basically want to transition both inline <script>'s to requirejs, and as I am automating the inclusion of all JS for a page (to be handled via requirejs), I generate paths and shim configs, and I cannot evaluate each script, to see which (if any) globals it requires.
If only I could get the amd-module into the non-amd-script's scope, or vice versa...

Comment: @c_kick I do not know about any generic solution, sorry :(

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered as it *is* a workable answer, just not exactly what I wanted, but I've concluded that this is not possible. Thanks!